# Replaced a picture; Picture disappeared WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a colleague who is free this week and who placed a banner (picture) above a WordPress website (above the theme). He used a picture for that that was uploaded within the WordPress. Now someone designed a new banner, That is slightly different than the other and I removed the old one and uploaded the new one. Thinking that would replace it.

Somehow the banner disappeared on the website after I did that. The picture is exactly the same in size and off course name. The banner is thus not within the theme of the WordPress site and I figured he made some code that would just use the folder with the image and paste that image above the WordPress theme. That apparently is not the case.

Any tips for me to find out what happened here and how to recover it? Contacting my colleague is not an option.

```
    <div id="header-top" class="header-bar-wrap"></div>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header clearfix" role="banner">

        <div class="header-main container clearfix">

            <div id="logo" class="site-branding clearfix">

                <a href="..." class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url"><img width="2318" height="200" src="....jpg" class="custom-logo" alt="la_banner_wp2" itemprop="logo" srcset="....jpg 2318w, ....jpg 300w, ....jpg 768w, ....jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 2318px) 100vw, 2318px" /></a>
```

This is the code that it should be. Somehow that changed to:

```
    <div id="header-top" class="header-bar-wrap"></div>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header clearfix" role="banner">

        <div class="header-main container clearfix">

            <div id="logo" class="site-branding clearfix">
```

Comment: did you upload the new image to exactly the same folder as the old one (i.e. replacing it there)?

Comment: No. When I did that it renamed the file with a -1 behind it. So after trying that I deleted the picture and uploaded the new one with exactly that name.

Comment: share your website URL

Comment: I found the header.php of the theme and just copied the code in there. The result works. Don't know if that is the best option and dont know what happened. Guess ill find out when my colleague returns.